# How do I limit a function's callers to a particular logged-in user or role using WWSAPI?

Tags: c++, web-services, wwsapi

I've been using http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haoxu/archive/2008/12/02/wwsapi-to-wcf-interop-nettcpbinding-with-transport-security.aspx as a guidelines on how to implement a secure connection using Windows Authentication.  The next step for me is to use this to limit approved callers to either a login or a role/Windows group.  I haven't been able to find out how to do this through the code samples I've found, so I'm wondering if anyone else has successfully implemented this.

Thanks for any help forthcoming.

Edit: I'm basically looking for the equivalent of C#'s PrincipalPermission attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation this isn't possible with WWSAPI.